# Efficient way of comparing two (unordered) lists for matches

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, list

Consider two collections of custom `Record` objects. What is an efficient method of searching these for matches? To clarify what is meant by a "match": each of the properties of instances of these objects are equal (they are only strings).

As a first pass, put them in two `List<Record>`. Then:

```
foreach (Record record1 in List1<Record>)
{
    foreach (Record record2 in List2<Record>)
    {
       // assume there is a match() method implemented which compares two Record objects
       if (match(record1,record2))
       {
            // write it to the console, add it to a list of matches, or other appropriate action
       }
    }
}
```

Note that the ordering of these objects does not matter.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Define "efficient". What have you tried so far? How fast was it? How much faster do you expect a competing solution to be? The LINQ `Intersect()` method is the de facto built-in way to produce the intersection of two unordered sequences, such as you're asking here. See marked duplicate for examples.